# After change regional settings, pages with SPFx webparts gives unexpected error has occurred

Tags: sharepoint-server, date-time, spfx, spfx-webparts, regional-settings

After change regional settings in SharePoint 2016 On-Premise server to Bulgarian, Macedonian оr other Locale
[image: untitled]

**I have following error:**
[image: untitled]

**Error from log file by corelation ID is:**

> Message  : System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.    at
>              System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideCachedThirdPartyComponentProvider.GetUpdateTimeFromAppCatalog(SPWebweb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideCachedThirdPartyComponentProvider.GetDistributedUpdateTime(Guid tenantId, SPWeb web)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideCachedThirdPartyComponentProvider.EnsureCacheIsValid(SPWeb web, Guid tenantId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideCachedThirdPartyComponentProvider.GetNotFoundComponents(SPClientSideComponentQueryResultCollection requests, SPWeb web)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideCom...

Thanks for your contribution! Sharing is caring.

Comment: This could be a bug in SPFx. Have you submitted an issue on GitHub at https://github.com/sharepoint/sp-dev-docs?

Comment: Yes, this is my issue - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/367

Comment: I have no answer for three days, and this stops me from working on the project..